# How to remote access jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using anaconda's jupyter notebook so far.
And now, I have to remote access to Win PC from MacBook.

So first, I created jupyter_notebook_config.py by typing
`jupyter --generate-config`

And I planned to modify that file to enter ip, password, port and things like that.
But here's the problem...
I can't find
`c.NotebookApp.`

There are,
`c.Application.`
`c.JupyterApp.`
`c.ExtensionApp.`
`c.LabServerApp`
`c.JupyterNotebookApp.`
`c.ServerApp`

How can I solve this?

1. I thought it might be a little different in the Anaconda environment, so I looked for it, but I couldn't find a way.
2. In Jupiter Labs,
   `c.ServerApp.`
   Some parts were seen being modified, but it was impossible to accurately determine whether it was related to remote access.

Answer (score 0):

So if you run it as

```
jupyter-notebook --ip="*"
```

The terminal will then display two links. If you visit the one which doesn't start with `http:/127.0...` on the Windows computer, that should work.

You shouldn't need to mess around with editing the config.

If you are on a public network, you can specify the Windows machine's specific internal IP address instead. For example

```
jupyter-notebook --ip="192.168.1.123"
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice first.  
  
I typed that you mentioned   
jupyter-notebook --ip="*"  
  
But the terminal displayed only one link,   
http://localhost:8888/tree  
  
Are there any other points I should check?

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to program and run the notebook, and you can connect with ssh to your windows machine, then VisualStudioCode has a very easy to use plugin to work on remote machines.

You can check it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

You will need to install all the plugins for running Jupyter notebooks with the integrated app store once you are connected to the remote. The IDE will likely suggest them directly when you open your .ipynb file.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  

So what you're saying is opening a server on an OS like Ubuntu and trying to connect to it with vscode?

Comment: Yes, there are options to create SSH servers on Windows as well if you need it.